# Upload file from file browser on local computer and append it to the page

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io

Trying to add an image file from my local computer onto the HTML page with no luck.

```
  document.getElementById("f_up").onchange = function(event) {
       // target tgets the element value that triggered this event
       var img = event.target
       console.log("This is the img")
       console.log(img)
       $('<li class="replies"><img src="{{ img }}"></li>').appendTo($('.messages ul'));
       $('.message-input input').val(null);
```

```
  <input type="file" id="f_up" style="display: none" accept="image/*">
```

I want the image to be shown on the screen. Console log is

```
<input id="f_up" type="file" style="display: none" accept="image/*">
```

which is strange since event.target is suppose to have gotten the image file....

Comment: web browser can't display local images if it display HTML from server - you would have to upload image on server first.

Comment: Your code rather doesn't upload file on server - it only get file's local name (path). Server has to receive POST request with file (data from `<form>`), save file in server's folder and put in HTML path to file on server.

Comment: Ah ok I get it now, so it is because the nature of img src that needs a directory or link where the image itself is hosted (and accessible), that means local files won't work. 

I was trying to wrap my head around how a WebSocket would receive and send files, that means it also needs to have a function to store the image onto the serve and create a src link to it, then later be appended onto the page!